# Is there any junction, or branch element for jumper cables?

Tags: jumper, junction

I would like to create circuits using jumper cables. I have male-female, male-male, and female-female jumper cables too. But I cant find any branching cable on ebay.

What should I use, to create branches without breadboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's be clear that "jumper cables" refers to little wires used to connect things on a breadboard, not to connect two car batteries together.

The usual answer is that the breadboard provides the multiple connections to a net.  The common solderless breadboards with lots of little sockets have 5 sockets wired together in a strip.  The provides enough sockets to connect multiple strips together using only single point to point jumper wires.  Technically only 3 sockets per strip are necessary for this to work and still allow components to be connected beyond the jumper wires, but 5 per strip gives you more flexibility and makes it easier to connect multiple components directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove a piece of the insulation in the middle of a cable. Cut another one in two and solder the side you need to the point where you removed the insulation. Take a fitting piece of heat-shrink tubing, put it around your soldered piece, apply some heat and you are done with a branch element.

If you don't have the equipment to solder, there are also branch connectors available, but they are a bit bulky for breadboard stuff. Something like [Posiplug](http://www.posi-products.com/posiplug.html), there are quite a few variants around.